# How to access connection section in Eclipse with JPA

Tags: eclipse, jpa

I am a Eclipse Luna user. When I create a new dynamic web project or JPA project, can not access  persistance.xml in connection section. No problem on the other tabs. Therefore ,  i write connection xml parts  in source section with manually.
How can fix this problem?

thanks..